# mockMVC method GET java.lang.AssertionError: Status Expected :200 Actual :500

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

i written a test in spring mockMVC this method:

my method testing is:

```
@Test
public void getAccount()throws Exception {
     mockMvc.perform(get("/account/1"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("/account/"));
}
```

and i have a following bug:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /users/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}
Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null
FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1], Content-Length=[14]}
     Content type = text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
             Body = We are doomed.
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :500
```

This is my POST method test:

what is bad in my test method? what i can fixed this?

I am asking for help and quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're not looking at the right place for the issue.

The logger outputs that you have an error with the request URI `/users/1`:

```
Request URI = /users/1
```

and your testing method is trying to get `/account/1`:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/account/1"))
```

As for the error itself, [MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.html):

> Exception that indicates that a method argument has not the expected type.

In other words, the method which is annotated by `@GetMapping("/users/{id}")` has the wrong `@PathVariable` parameter type.

In your case, you're using [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as parameter:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> getAccount(@PathVariable UUID id) {
```

However, in your test, you're not passing a UUID, you're passing a numerical value (long/int) in your test.

If you want to generate a random UUID, you can use `UUID.randomUUID()`:

```
@Test
public void getAccount()throws Exception {
     mockMvc.perform(get("/account/" + UUID.randomUUID()))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("/account/"));
}
```

Alternatively, you could use long instead of uuid in your mapping method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve account.")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> getAccount(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return accountService.retreiveById(id).map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

though in that case, you'll probably have to change your `AccountService.retrieveById(id)` method.

Good luck!